# Use replaceAll() in Java to replace symbol using original leading and trailing character(s)

Tags: java, regex, replace

I want to replace all `@` symbols that exist after a `(` or a `' '`, and that exist before any of the following characters `[.,;?!:) ]`. I want to replace them with a double quote `"` symbol, but I want to keep the original leading and trailing characters.

For example, if I have the following text:

```
Hello @world@!
```

I want it to become:

```
Hello "world"!
```

But if I have the following text:

```
user@email.com
```

It **shouldn't** change...

```
user@email.com
```

I currently have the following code:

```
String text = "Hello @world@!";
text = text.replaceAll("[ (]@[.,;?:) ]","\"");
```

This replaces the `@` symbol with double quotes, but it also removes the leading and trailing characters, which I don't want. How can I preserve the leading and trailing characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to keep the leading and/or trailing characters used for recognizing the target sequence of characters, use *lookahead* or *lookbehind* features of the regex - a way to specify a sequence of characters that must be present, but *not* be consumed:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?<=[ (])@|@(?=[.,;?:) !])", "\"");
```

([demo](http://ideone.com/IkYo8h))

A simpler, less specific, regex may work as well - use the *word boundary* marker `\b` to indicate that the `@` must occur on a word boundary:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\b@|@\\b", "\"");
```

([demo](http://ideone.com/uXskAu))